# On the number of length-$4$ words over $\{a, b, c\}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

> Given the alphabet $\Sigma := \{ a, b, c \}$, find the number of all possible length-$4$ words over $\Sigma$.

---

In this case, the order does of course matter and it is also the case that same letter can appear multiple times in the word. So the total amount of possibilities is $3^4$.

What I do not understand is the following case. Let's say I have the word $abbc$ and then I switch the two $b$'s with each other and become $abbc$ but the first $abbc$ is the same as the second $abbc$, so in this specific case the order doesn't matter? But when forming words we say that the order does matter.
Does anyone see where it went wrong in my explanation?

Comment: There is only one way to obtain the word $abbc$: choose an  $a$ for the first position, $b$s for the second and third positions, and a $c$ for the fourth position.  Your count for the number of four-letter words that can be formed from the alphabet $\{a, b, c\}$ is correct.  Asking how many distinguishable ways the letters of the word $abbc$ can be permuted is a different question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you, I think I start to understand it a little bit better.

Comment: The whole "order matters" / "order doesn't matter" thing seems to confuse students more than it helps them. It's better to just understand why the answer in this case is $3^4$, than to worry about whether the order of repeated letters matters.